# Value Matching and reduce dimension in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a data file which consist of Marks of two subjects.

The file look like that

Sl_No:  Marks1   Marks2

```
1      10       20
2      10       20
3      10       20
4      10       20  
5      10       10
6      20       10
7      20       10
8      20       10
9      20       30
10     20       22
11     21       22
12     21       22
13     21       23
14     10       20
15     10       20
```

Now my objective is that whenever it get same pair of value add this marks. So as per my example sl_no 1 to 4 have same pairs of values (10,20). So it return 40 for Marks1 and 80 for marks2. Sl_No: 5 doesnot match with sl_no: 4 so it is remain same. Serial no: 6 to 8 have a matching pair so it return 60 and 30. Sl_no: 9.0 and  10.0 has no match so it remain same as it is. Sl_no: 11 and 12 had a match so return 42 and 44.and sl_no: 14 and 15 had a match so return 20 and 40.

Desired output:

```
4  40  80
5  10  10
8  60  30
9  20  30
10 20  22
12 42  44
13 21  23
15 20  40
```

My Code:

```
public class Marksmatch {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int []sl_no={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    int []Marks1={10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,10,10};
    int []Marks2={20,20,20,20,10,10,10,10,30,22,22,22,23,20,20};
    int addMarks1=0,addMarks2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<sl_no.length-1;i++){
        if(Marks1[i]== Marks1[i+1]&&Marks2[i]==Marks2[i+1]){
            addMarks1=addMarks1+Marks1[i+1];
            addMarks2=addMarks2+Marks2[i+1];
            System.out.println(addMarks1);
            System.out.println(addMarks2);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Output:
  10
20
20
40
30
60
50
70
70
80
91
102
101
122

It did not give me the desire output. How could I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. You should keep track of the sums of the current group, and only print them once you are done with the group:

```
int addMarks1=Marks1[0],addMarks2=Marks2[0]; // initialize the sums of the first group
for(int i=0;i<sl_no.length-1;i++){
    if(Marks1[i]== Marks1[i+1] && Marks2[i]==Marks2[i+1]) {
        // add to the current group
        addMarks1=addMarks1+Marks1[i+1];
        addMarks2=addMarks2+Marks2[i+1];
    } else {
        // print the previous group and start a new group
        System.out.println(sl_no[i] + " " + addMarks1 + " " + addMarks2);
        addMarks1=Marks1[i+1];
        addMarks2=Marks2[i+1];
    }
}
// print the last group
System.out.println(sl_no[sl_no.length-1] + " " + addMarks1 + " " + addMarks2)
```

Output:

```
4 40 80
5 10 10
8 60 30
9 20 30
10 20 22
12 42 44
13 21 23
15 20 40
```

Comment: If I want to write the first value of the group member like 4 40 80 is in group 1 10 20 . So before 4 40 80 this 1 10 20 will written and that is repeat for each group . What portion will be modified?